# Is there a way to develop on Sitecore 10 using ASP.NET Core without Docker

Tags: helix

All the [Helix.Examples](https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples/tree/master/examples/helix-basic-aspnetcore) use docker containers. Can I develop Dot Net Core based solution without using docker for Sitecore 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes is possible to use Sitecore 10 using asp.net core rendering without docker.

Here you find all the information you need:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sitecore-headless-development-using-dotnetcore-sdk-without-uzzaman/
https://cmsclub9.wordpress.com/2020/11/23/net-core-sitecore-10-but-no-docker/

Comment: Link only answer, please add the relevant parts to your answer here.